# Perl: Why can't divide?

Tags: perl, divide

Why divide is not working?

```
echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 ))/e'

Number found where operator expected at -e line 1, near
"s/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4" syntax error at -e line 1, near
"s/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4" Execution of -e aborted due to
compilation errors.
```

Raw input data is 12 bits hex number.

Comment: The `/` in your division is seen as the delimiter for the regular expression. Why are you doing divisions in the replacement part? What is your input data? Most likely, `unpack` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default delimiter for substitution s/// is not balanced, so  you get the error. This is because you are dividing the $1 by 4 and it introduced another '/' . So to be safe use some other character other than the one that would mess with the expression. In this case better use <> as delimtier

```
$ echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's<(\w{3})><sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 ))>e '
812
```

when you convert s/// with other delimiters, you have to pair <...>, (...), [...] and {...}. I chose <> as it is not there in the expression.

Comment: You haven't explained why you think `<...>` is a better choice than, for example, `|...|`. And you should explain why `/.../.../` becomes `<...><...>` - with two delimiters in the middle.

Comment: Re "*I chose `<>` as it is not there is the expression.*", The best part of `<>` is that it's fine if `<` and `>` are part of the expression, as long as they are paired. This is far more likely to happen with `{}`, making it a better choice in general.

Comment: I tend to use `#` (hash, or pound), and thus `'s#(\w{3})#sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 ))#e' formats work fine for me

(though it did confuse the gvim syntax highlighter, that thought the `#` was a comment :) )

Comment: # -- for comments and  "|" for  piping to other commands..so my best practice in this case is to go for <>

Comment: *when you convert s/// with other delimiters other than | (pipe) , you have to use them in pair* That's not true. You have to pair `<...>`, `(...)`, `[...]` and `{...}`. All other characters (not just `|`) can be used unpaired.

Comment: @stack0114106: The full details [are here](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: Talking of preferences, mine is `m{}{}`.  I guess because code blocks are written that way anyway, and these are code blocks of sorts.  (What, of course, could be used as a reason against -- to do something _else_ ! Just preference :)

Comment: yeah..me too. I first used ````{}```` in the answer, but then to explain better to the OP, switched to <>

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work:

```
$ echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 ))/e'
Unknown regexp modifier "/4" at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 )"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This does:

```
$ echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)\/4 ))/e'
812
```

So does this, and it might be easier to follow:

```
$ echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's|(\w{3})|sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)/4 ))|e'
812
```

When you use a `/` character as the separator character in a substitution, then all occurrences of `/` in your expression will be seen as separators. If you want one to be see as something else (a division operator, for example) you need to escape it (by putting `\` in front of it).

Another option is to choose a different separator for your substitution. In my third example, I've switched to using `|` instead. In this case, the `/` is no longer seen as special and doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a different delimiter for the substitution or you will need to escape the divide with a backslash:

```
echo 'cb0' | perl -p -e 's/(\w{3})/sprintf("%d", ( hex($1)\/4 ))/e'
```